# apache - DirectoryIndex - php page with arguments

Tags: apache, arguments, directoryindex

I've got a single tikiwiki instance and several domain names. I want domain-1.com to have a homepage at domain-1.com/tiki-index.php?page-1. And then I want domain-2.com to have a homepage at domain-2.com/tiki-index.php?page-2. Both will internally map to the same tikiwiki instance.

I.e. I want several domains to point to the same tikiwiki instance. But coming from different domains should land you at different home pages. And then user could manually navigate from `domain-1.com/tiki-index.php?page-1` (hompage) to `domain-1.com/tiki-index.php?page-2`

I tried to do this by setting `DirectoryIndex` but looks like it ignores all page arguments, i.e. `?page-1`.

Any clues how to make an index page with arguments?

Comment: Apache DirectoryIndex directive https://amitoverflow.com/2021/04/29/how-to-use-directoryindex/

Answer (score 0):

did it mylsef

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  "^/$"
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http://domain-1.com/tiki-index.php?page=page-1"
```

The key here is to set rewrite condition to match **empty** URI, that is the default address - `http://domain-1.com`